# Largest Cylinder inside Polyhedron

Tags: optimization

Imagine you have a  piece of wood and from that piece you want to get the largest cylinder possible.

**How do you determine the position and orientation of the cylinders axis, to maximize its radius?**

I've been looking at this problem for over a year now and I can't find an efficient (or rather *any*) algorithm that can handle 200000 vertices in a second.

My current idea is a simple:

1. slicing up the piece,
2. finding the centroid of the slice
3. and using a best fit line through the slices' centroids

...but that's rather considering weight distribution of the polyhedron than in-cylinder.

I have been looking at voronoi diagrams and medial axis, as well as straight skeletons. With these I could possibly get something from which I could generate an axis, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Thankful for any help or hint or full description of an algorithm.

Comment: You're talking about cutting a 3D cylinder out of a 3D chunk of wood, right?  How are you determining "largest" for the cylinder?  By volume or by axis length or radius length?  Or are you talking about cutting a circle out from a 2D plane of wood?

Comment: yes, a largest by radius 3D cylinder out of a 3D chunk of wood.

Comment: also you can assume that the piece of wood is a trunk, so almost like a cylinder but not quite

Comment: A polygon is a two-dimensional shape. Do you mean a *polyhedron* (often represented as a *polygon mesh*)?

Comment: @Rahul oops, thanks for clearing that up for me

Comment: @MarkusHütter. If we are allowed to assume the piece is already cylinder-like: Could you do a Principal Component Analysis to find the dominant "axis" and continue from there? It would give you a reasonable initial position to do a global optimization as Geoff suggests.

Comment: @ Andre I do a PCA for my #3, haven't tried it on all the points. How to go from there I need to read up a bit on! The main problem I guess is, that it's not convex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to solve a variant of the diamond cutting problem; you might try searching for this term and seeing what you come up with.

The number of decision variables should be relatively small -- you need the radius of the cylinder, its center of mass, its height, and the orientation of the axis in 3-D (a vector of unit length, in essence). From there, you should be able to formulate equations that describe the locus of points that make up the cylinder, and all of these should be within your feasible region. If you can describe your feasible region with equations, this information should be enough to formulate your problem.

Upon formulating the problem, I believe it will be nonconvex (if memory serves, an example came up in a global optimization class I TAed), in which case, you need to use a global optimization algorithm to solve the resulting optimization problem. BARON is usually the solver of choice, although it is closed-source and only has a GAMS interface, I believe. You could try using Couenne or Bonmin as solvers also, although these codes are not regarded as highly as BARON.

Comment: Taking the block of wood to be the union of two intersecting cylinders does suggest that the problem can be quite nonconvex.

Comment: +1 thanks Geoff, the term "diamond cutting problem" did indeed give me a new direction to do some research as it does appear similar. What I could find sounds quite interesting but I wonder if that will be fast enough. I'll continue reading some more now, solving problems like this is new to me (I mean this deep matrix transformation stuff and inequations and so on...)!